# Run line editing for user input (script command)

Tags: shell, line-editor

I used the `script` program to record an interactive session:

```
$ script
$ echo<-<-<-<-printf "hello\n"
$ exit
```

The sequence `<-` is representing the backspace character.

I want the following as output:

```
$ printf "hello\n"
$ exit
```

But the actual result contains all individual keystrokes (looking with `cat --show-nonprinting`).

I tried reading line-by-line with the `read` command. It does edit out the backspaces, but it also removes the command prompt, and it seems it converts `\n` into `n`.

I'm looking for a way to have the text the user was seeing on screen (command prompt, edited input and command output -- colors don't matter).

---

For reference a sample output:

```
^[[?2004l^M^[[?2004h$ echo^H^[[K^H^[[K^H^[[K^H^[[Kprintf "hello\n"^M
^[[?2004l^Mhello^M
^[[?2004h$ exit^M
^[[?2004l^Mexit^M
```

Comment: Will `scriptreplay` help? Those strings (ESC [ digits ; digits m) are "VT100 Control Sequences", and are influenced by the `$TERM` environment variable. I've used an Emacs function to eliminate them from my `script` logs, but suggesting "Learn Emacs" is extreme overkill.

Comment: @waltinator no, the output is virtually the same with scriptreplay

Comment: From your reference sample, you seem to have quite complex a prompt including exotic (?) console codes, and there are several control characters missing, like `^M` (0x0D, <CR>), `^H` (0x08, <BS>), and `^[` (`0x1B`; <ESC>). Why not start debugging with simpler, straight forward examples? And, why wouldn't  `cat file | while read -r ...`  work?

Comment: @RudiCcorrect, I have a custom PS1, will try with a simpler PS1 and see how that goes. I recall seeing ^M, ^H, not sure why it's missing in the sample.

Comment: @RudiC replaced the sample with PS1="$ ", ^H, ^M are there

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, [ansi2txt](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ansi2txt) will do
exactly what you want:

```
$ ansi2txt typescript > ANSI2TXT
$ cat ANSI2TXT
$ printf "hello\n"
hello
$ exit

Script done on Wed 15 Apr 2020 07:48:55 PM CEST
```

Comment: it looks promising, since it prints the command prompt as well and the escaped \n